# Java - Trying to understand how overloading methods work

Tags: java, overloading

I just started learning Java and I have a problem regarding method-overloading.

I want to know if I can call a variation of an overloaded method inside the scope of another variation of the overloaded method in question.

My main question is:
What problems could possibly arise from doing that?

For example:

```
public class RoomClass {

    int roomNo = 1;
    String roomType = "Lecture Hall";
    String roomArea = "First Floor";
    boolean ACMachine = true;

    protected void setData(int roomNo, String roomType, String roomArea, boolean ACMachine) {

        setData(roomNo);
        setData(roomType, roomArea);
        setData(ACMachine);
    }

    protected void setData(int roomNo) {
        this.roomNo = roomNo;
    }

    protected void setData(String roomType, String roomArea) {

        this.roomType = roomType;
        this.roomArea = roomArea;
    }

    protected void setData(boolean ACMachine) {

        this.ACMachine = ACMachine;
    }
}
```

The code above is about an exercise. I couldn't find an answer to my question online or in a book.
What I am trying to do is to avoid repeating code, so I figured "why not call on the other methods, since they are doing exactly what I need?". So I just aggregated all the other methods into the first one.

Comment: why not just run your program and find out?

Comment: The code I was writing was about an exercise in java (beginner level). I wanted to know if this example could be viable in large projects, or if it would create problems.

P.S. I did run the program before posting the question and it worked fine.

Comment: it wont arise any problem according to me...  analogy - suppose you have a window in an office where it took the form with all details ( first function ) then within its office it has different people with different responsibilities ( other functions ) which it will send the data to process , it could be same designation person but with one specific task to perform ( e.g setData(int roomNo) )  or could be another person with different designation with different task... they can all call each other whenever its required... hope it helps..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only is it safe, it's a very common thing to do. Java doesn't have default parameter values, so you'll often see overloads with fewer parameters calling overloads with more parameters and supplying default values.  For example:

```
public void foo(int a, int b) {
    // do something with a and b
}

public void foo(int a) {
    // supply default value of 0 for b
    foo(a, 0);
}
```

One problem that can arise is if someone extends your class and overrides `foo(int, int)`. This will also affect the behavior of `foo(int)`, which may be unexpected. To prevent this, you can make `foo(int, int)` or the entire class `final`. If you allow extension, you should document which methods call other methods. This is a rare exception to the rule that you should not document implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in doing so as programmatically it is correct.Overloaded methods can be called from another overloaded method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem at all. Java Virtual Machine can identify overloaded methods separately by the number of arguments and the data types. I don't see any problem in your example.